# OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied while executing python script from USB drive

Tags: python, subprocess

I get this error when I try to run the Python script from my USB drive. I have copied over all the files from my current directory on to a USB stick for the Python script to run from another Ubuntu machine.

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1545, in __call__
  return self.func(*args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 402, in button_press_event
  FigureCanvasBase.button_press_event(self, x, y, num, dblclick=dblclick, guiEvent=event)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 1909, in button_press_event
  self.callbacks.process(s, mouseevent)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 549, in process
  proxy(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 416, in __call__
  return mtd(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/widgets.py", line 434, in _update
  self.set_val(val)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/widgets.py", line 448, in set_val
  func(val)
File "/media/mghansar/MG/ktn/UQM_Prototype_V1.03_RD4.py", line 509, in update_slider1
  updateval_slider1(self.mu_a1,self.sigma_a1)
File "/media/mghansar/MG/ktn/UQM_Prototype_V1.03_RD4.py", line 488, in updateval_slider1
  getout1= self.surrogate_call(in5)
File "/media/mghansar/MG/ktn/UQM_Prototype_V1.03_RD4.py", line 431, in surrogate_call
  process = Popen([binary_name, '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
  errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
  raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

It works fine when I execute the program from its current directory in Ubuntu 16.10.

The script tries to read an executable file when it throws the above error. Below is the relevant code

```
    def surrogate_call(self,inputs, binary_name='./ktn-sgp'):
    '''
    @param inputs pandas.DataFrame (one row per input point)
    '''
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
    from StringIO import StringIO

    # call the surrogate compiled from C code
    process = Popen([binary_name, '-'], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    (stdout_data, stderr_data) = process.communicate(inputs.to_csv(header=False, index=False))
    exit_code = process.wait()
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access to read and write on the drive?

Comment: Have you checked the Linux permissions and groups of the file on the USB, are they the same as on the machine? Type `ll`

Comment: @Burhan Khalid, cardamom:  Owner (Me) has access to read and write. 'Group' and 'Others' have read-only access to the file and folder. The difference between permission in the directory and USB is the check box 'Allow executing file as program' option is checked in the current directory whereas it is unchecked in the USB drive. When I try to check on that option it doesnt let me.

Answer (score 0):

Your USB drive is most likely FAT formatted, and FAT does not contain unix style file permissions.

You have two options:

1) If you can control the system and decide how it mounts the USB drive, you can follow this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/499275/how-to-set-usb-drive-with-executable-permission to mount the drive. Key parts are mount options exec, uid, gid and umask.  You need to tell the operating system who owns the files on USB drive as FAT does not contain this information, and allow execution from the drive. Umask=022 sets permissions of the files to rwxr-xr-x enabling the execute bit as this information is missing on FAT as well.

2) If that is not possible, the only way I can see is to execute python instead of your script. Instead of calling the script directly, call /usr/bin/python with your script location on usb drive as the first argument. This does not require execute privileges as Python will read in the file using read permissions.

Hannu